# Exchange 2010 - Powershell to remove Send On Behalf permission

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, send-on-behalf-of

I'm trying to run the command below to remove e Send On Behalf permission, but i'm getting an exception and it removes all the users that have access, instead of the one I specify in my script

```
$owner = "lpeter" 
$remove = "jdoe"

$grantlist = Get-Mailbox $owner -DomainController tordc01 | select -ExpandProperty GrantSendOnB

$grantlist = $grantlist |?{$_.Name -ne $remove} 
Set-Mailbox $owner -GrantSendOnBehalfTo $null -DomainController tordc01
$grantlist | %{
    Set-Mailbox $owner -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{Add=$_.Name} -Confirm $true
} -DomainController tordc01
```

here is the exception :

```
ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'Process'. Cannot convert the
"-DomainController" value of type "System.String" to type
"System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock". At line:1 char:15
+ $grantlist | % <<<< {Set-Mailbox $owner -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{Add=$_.Name} -Confirm $true} -DomainController tordc01

     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is pretty self-explanatory, you're trying to supply the `-DomainController` parameter to `ForEach-Object`, instead of to `Set-Mailbox`

Change the last statement to:

```
$grantlist | %{
    Set-Mailbox $owner -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{Add=$_.Name} -Confirm:$true -DomainController tordc01
}
```

Comment: Here is th exception I get now after changing the last statement A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'True'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Mailbox], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Set-Mailbox

Comment: Change `-Confirm $true` to `-Confirm:$true`. Use `-Confirm:$false` if you want to avoid confirming every user added